# C++ String class implementation

Tags: c++, performance, strings, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel

I wrote a simple String class implementation using `unique_ptr` and move semantics. Is my implementation good enough in terms of design and efficiency?

#### Stringy.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>

class Stringy {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> p;
    std::size_t size;
    std::size_t len;

    enum {Factor = 3};

    static void _debug(const char *x)
    {
    #if DEBUG
        std::cout << "=> " << x << " <=" << std::endl;
    #endif
    }

public:

    Stringy(const char* ptr);
    Stringy(const Stringy& Other);
    Stringy(Stringy&& Other);

    const Stringy& operator=(Stringy Other);
    const Stringy& operator=(Stringy&& Other);

    void swap(Stringy& Other);

    void concat(const Stringy& Other);
    void concat(const char* One);

    void move(Stringy& Other);

    std::size_t length() const;

    Stringy operator+(const Stringy& Other) const;
    Stringy operator+(const char* ptr) const;

    const char& operator[](std::size_t index) const;
    char& operator[](std::size_t index);

    friend Stringy&& operator+ (Stringy&& Lhs, const char* Rhs);
    friend Stringy&& operator+ (Stringy&& Lhs, const Stringy& Rhs);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& cout, const Stringy& Other);

    ~Stringy();
};
```

#### Stringy.cpp

```
#define DEBUG false

Stringy::Stringy(const char *ptr)
{
    _debug("default pointer Ctor");
    len = strlen(ptr);
    size = len * Factor;
    p = std::make_unique<char[]>(size);
    std::copy(ptr, ptr + len, p.get());
    p[len] = '\0';
}

Stringy::Stringy(const Stringy &Other): size(Other.size), len(0)
{
    _debug("Copy Ctor");
    p = std::make_unique<char[]>(size);
    concat(Other);
}

Stringy::Stringy(Stringy &&Other)
{
    _debug("Move Ctor");
    move(Other);
}

const Stringy& Stringy::operator=(Stringy Other)
{
    _debug("opterator= copy and swap");
    swap(Other);
    return *this;
}

const Stringy& Stringy::operator=(Stringy &&Other)
{
    _debug("Move operator=");
    move(Other);
    return *this;
}

void Stringy::swap(Stringy &Other)
{
    std::swap(size, Other.size);
    std::swap(len, Other.len);
    std::swap(p, Other.p);
}

//TODO: Reallocate memory if required
void Stringy::concat(const Stringy &Other)
{
    std::copy(Other.p.get(), Other.p.get() + Other.len, p.get() + len);
    len += Other.len;
    p[len] = '\0';
}

//TODO: Reallocate memory if required
void Stringy::concat(const char *One)
{
    std::size_t _len = strlen(One);
    std::copy(One, One + _len, p.get() + len);
    len += _len;
    p[len] = '\0';
}

void Stringy::move(Stringy &Other)
{
    size = Other.size;
    Other.size = 0;

    len = Other.len;
    Other.len = 0;

    p = std::move(Other.p);
    Other.p = NULL;
}

std::size_t Stringy::length() const
{
    return len;
}

Stringy Stringy::operator+(const Stringy &Other) const
{
    _debug("operator+ Other");
    Stringy temp(*this);
    temp.concat(Other);
    return temp;
}

Stringy Stringy::operator+(const char *ptr) const
{
    _debug("operator+ ptr");
    Stringy temp(*this);
    temp.concat(ptr);
    return temp;
}

const char& Stringy::operator[](std::size_t index) const
{
    return this->p[index];
}

char& Stringy::operator[](std::size_t index)
{
    return this->p[index];
}

Stringy::~Stringy()
{
    _debug("Dtor");
}

Stringy&& operator+(Stringy &&Lhs, const char *Rhs)
{
    Stringy::_debug("operator+ move ptr");
    Lhs.concat(Rhs);
    return std::move(Lhs);
}

Stringy&& operator+(Stringy &&Lhs, const Stringy &Rhs)
{
    Stringy::_debug("operator+ move Other");
    Lhs.concat(Rhs);
    return std::move(Lhs);
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const Stringy &Other)
{
    stream << Other.p.get();
    return stream;
}
```

I benchmarked the class against `std::string` on QuickBench and it shows 2.5x worse performance, but that's because gcc now uses SSO. With large string size, my class performed comparably to `std::string` although I would agree they are little biased.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stringy.h"

void custom() {
    Stringy firstName = "Sumit";
    Stringy lastName = "Dhingra";
    Stringy fullName = firstName + "-" + ">" + lastName;

    std::cout << fullName << std::endl;
}

void default_() {
    std::string firstName = "Sumit";
    std::string lastName = "Dhingra";
    std::string fullName = firstName + "-" + ">" + lastName;

    std::cout << fullName << std::endl;
}

int main() {
#ifdef DEFAULT
    default_();
#else
    custom();
#endif
}
```

Comment: SSO can mean single sign-on, structure sequence and organization and a boat load of other things. Which do you mean?

Comment: Short String Optimization. Sorry for not clearing it up.

Comment: `stringy.cpp` is obviously incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `private:` is redundant: While `union` and `struct` default to `public`, `class` already defaults to `private`.
2. Calling the capacity `size` is seriously counter-intuitive. `std::string` has `.length()` as a legacy-method which is equal to `.size()`.
3. A factor of two or more when re-allocating is seriously sub-optimal: It inhibits re-use of returned memory-blocks when expanding bit by bit.
4. Unconditionally over-allocating on creation is in general a serious pessimisation.
5. Why does `_debug()` use `cout` instead of `cerr`?
6. Any reason you use your own macro, instead of re-using [`assert()`'s `NDEBUG`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert)?
7. It's curious that assignment accepts an rvalue-reference or a copy, but not a constant reference. Also consider accepting a `const char*` like the ctor does.
8. Construction from `const char*` will write out-of-bounds if passed a 0-length string.
9. Why write the nul-terminator in an extra step when you can simply copy that too?
10. [`std::copy_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) seems to fit your use better than `std::copy()`.
11. Not doing the move in the move-ctor, but delegating to a separate method called `move()`, is seriously weird.
12. `+=` is the operator for concatenation. Why do you call it `concat()`?
13. Consider consolidating the methods accepting a non-modifiable range to one using iterators. Excepting those which might use the fact that the source-range *is* actually already nul-terminated.
14. You can restrict member-functions to only be called on xvalues:

    ```
    friend Stringy&& operator+ (const char* Other) &&;
    friend Stringy&& operator+ (const Stringy& Other) &&;
    ```

    If you are at it, consider doing the same for `+=`.
15. If a function does not *need* to have the access, don't declare it a `friend`.
16. Take advantage of templates to run the same code with `std::string` and your own `Stringy`.

Comment: `clog` is more appropriate than `cerr` for debugging messages, IMO